# Array in encode JSON

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I Need Help on `JSON`. How can i do something like this in php using `JSON ENCODING`?
Basically this is the output I want.

```
{
"133": ["User1","assets/hey.jpg","a"],
"244": ["User2 Cobain","assets/aa.jpg","b"],
"3": ["User4","assets/abc.jpg","c"]
}
```

format of this one is {"userid":["fullname","img_path","add_info"]}

```
<?php 
include("../includes/connection.php");
$search= $mysqli->query("Select * from login_credentials");
        while($row = $search->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $userid = $row['UserID'];

            $fullname = $row['Fname'] . " " . $row['Lname'];
            //"133": []
        $c = array($fullname,'..//assets/elvis.jpg','http://html5-ninja.com');

            echo json_encode(array($user=>$c));             
        }
?>
```

Comment: you need to decode this json in php?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ninju . i need to create a JSON from php which output that like that one above.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but json_decode() creates an array like this:

```
array:3 [
  133 => array:3 [
    0 => "User1"
    1 => "assets/hey.jpg"
    2 => "a"
  ]
  244 => array:3 [
    0 => "User2 Cobain"
    1 => "assets/aa.jpg"
    2 => "b"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    0 => "User4"
    1 => "assets/abc.jpg"
    2 => "c"
  ]
]
```

Code:

```
  $json = '{
       "133": ["User1","assets/hey.jpg","a"],
       "244": ["User2 Cobain","assets/aa.jpg","b"],
       "3": ["User4","assets/abc.jpg","c"]
  }';
  var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```